# Create a matrix that contains 1 if there is a 1 in the bottom-right corner

Tags: python, numpy

Given a matrix M `n*n` (containing only `0` and `1`), I want to build the matrix that contains a `1` in position `(i, j)` if and only if there is at least a 1 in the bottom-right submatrix `M[i:n, j:n]`

Please note that I know there are optimal algorithm to compute this, but for performance reasons, I'm looking for a solution **using numpy (so the algorithm is fully compiled)**

Example:

Given this matrix:

```
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 0
```

I'm looking for a way to compute this matrix:

```
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

Thanks

Comment: what would be the desired result if the matrix was all zeros (except for bottom left cell)? ... is the second cell in bottom row correct?

Comment: Your question title says "bottom-right", the question text says "bottom-left" and `M[i:n, j:n]` implies bottom-right. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, I mean bottom right

Comment: *"I'm looking for a solution..."* That's not quite how this site works...

Comment: Hey @SiHa can you please enlighten me ? I don't really see the problem with my question

Comment: You have stated your problem, but with no attempt at solving it yourself. This is not how StackOverflow works. If you have a specific problem with code you have written, then, by all means post *that* with a concise description of the problem. This is not the place to come to, and simply expect others to write your code for you (although, as we see here, kind-hearted souls often will)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, here I thought that any piece of code would have been useless as I was asking for a function in the NumPy documentation (`np.maximum.accumulate`), I didn't even knew this function existed. It is more a "Is there a builtin numpy function that can perform this task" question

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy, you can accumulate the maximum value over each axis:

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[0,0,0,0,1],
              [0,0,1,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,1],
              [1,0,1,0,0]])

M = np.maximum.accumulate(M)
M = np.maximum.accumulate(M,axis=1)

print(M)
[[0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1]]
```

*Note: This matches your example result (presence of 1 in top-left quadrant). Your explanations of the logic would produce a different result however*

If we go with `M[i:n,j:n]` (bottom-right):

```
M = np.array([[0,0,0,0,1],
              [0,0,1,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,1],
              [1,0,1,0,0]])

M = np.maximum.accumulate(M[::-1,:])[::-1,:]
M = np.maximum.accumulate(M[:,::-1],axis=1)[:,::-1]

print(M)
[[1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 0]]
```

*It is essentially the same approach except with reversed accumulation on the axes*

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks for this detailed answer !